# How can I use templates to determine the appropriate argument passing method?

Tags: c++, templates, type-traits

As I understand it, when passing an object to a function that's larger than a register, it's preferable to pass it as a (const) reference, e.g.:

```
void foo(const std::string& bar)
{
    ...
}
```

This avoids having to perform a potentially expensive copy of the argument.

However, when passing a type that fits into a register, passing it as a (const) reference is at best redundant, and at worst slower:

```
void foo(const int& bar)
{
    ...
}
```

My problem is, I'd like to know how to get the best of both worlds when I'm using a templated class that needs to pass around either type:

```
template <typename T>
class Foo
{
  public:

    // Good for complex types, bad for small types
    void bar(const T& baz);   

    // Good for small types, but will needlessly copy complex types
    void bar2(T baz);             
};
```

Is there a template decision method that allows me to pick the correct type?  Something that would let me do,

```
void bar(const_nocopy<T>::type baz);
```

that would pick the better method depending on the type?

---

**Edit:**

After a fair amount of timed tests, the difference between the two calling times is different, but very small.  The solution is probably a dubious micro-optimization for my situation.  Still, [TMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_metaprogramming) is an interesting mental exercise.

Comment: Just a note, (not really a direct answer to your question) I think you will need to use typename like this: `void bar(typename const_nocopy<T>::type baz);`

Comment: Do you *really* need to work out that optimization??

Comment: 'How do we convince people that in programming simplicity and clarity —in short: what mathematicians call "elegance"— are not a dispensable luxury, but a crucial matter that decides between success and failure?' --Edsger Dijkstra

Comment: @dribeas If I could +1000 your comments I would do so

Comment: Sometimes performance is not a luxury too.

Comment: @EFraim: I think you are missing Dijkstra's point. But in this situation any effeciency gained will be so neglagable that the time to code and maintain it correctly it will so far exceed any savings gained that elegance will always win (even if the code is in use for non-stop for the next two melinia).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [Boost.CallTraits](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_39_0/libs/utility/call_traits.htm):

```
#include <boost/call_traits.hpp>

template <typename T>
void most_efficient( boost::call_traits<T>::param_type t ) {
    // use 't'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

If variable copy time is significant, the compiler will likely inline that instance of a template anyway, and the const reference thing will be just as efficient.

Technically you already gave yourself an answer.

Just specialize the `no_copy<T>` template for all the nocopy types.

```
template <class T> struct no_copy { typedef const T& type; };

template <> struct no_copy<int> { typedef int type; };
```

Comment: I suppose boost would have a is_pod<T> trait to avoid doing all those specializations?

Comment: is_pod is not really of help. You can have a really large POD (think of Win32 API structures), which you clearly want to pass by const reference.

Answer (score 1):

The only solution I can think of is using a macro to generate a specialized template version for smaller classes.

Answer (score 1):

**First:** Use `const &` - if the implementation is to large to be inlined, the cosnt & vs. argument doesn't make much of a difference anymore.

**Second:** This is the best I could come up with. Doesn't work correctly, because the compiler cannot deduce the argument type

```
template <typename T, bool UseRef> 
struct ArgTypeProvider {};

template <typename T>
struct ArgTypeProvider<T, true>
{
   typedef T const & ArgType;
};

template <typename T>
struct ArgTypeProvider<T, false>
{
   typedef T ArgType;
};

template <typename T>
struct ArgTypeProvider2 : public ArgTypeProvider<T, (sizeof(T)>sizeof(long)) >
{
};

// ----- example function
template <typename T>
void Foo(typename ArgTypeProvider2<T>::ArgType arg)
{
   cout << arg;
}

// ----- use
std::string s="fdsfsfsd";
// doesn't work :-(
// Foo(7);
// Foo(s);

// works :-)
Foo<int>(7);
Foo<std::string>(s);
```

Comment: Both your first and second advice seconded by me. Just a nitpick: I'd do sizeof(T)>sizeof(long) or something along those lines in order to be platform-independent.

Comment: thanks sbi, good suggestion - I've updated the sample accordingly.